# Probability properties

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There are 8 letters written, but the addresses on the envelopes are written at random.

What is the likelihood that:
a) at least one of the three recipients will receive the letter intended for him?
b) Will three addressees receive the corresponding letters?

I began to reason like this:

We fix one letter that gets to its address, and the remaining 7 will not get, then the probability that one letter gets is equal to $ 1/8$.After that, it is necessary to calculate the probability of the remaining seven letters that will not get to their addressees. Unfortunately at this point I am stuck. I think to use the formula:
$$
|A|=C_{2}^2=2
$$
$$
|\Omega| = C_{7}^2\cdot\ C_{6}^1=126.
$$
$$
\mathbb P(A)= \frac{|A|}{|\Omega|}\ = \frac{2}{126}=0.01587
$$
But I'm not really sure. Can you help with this part?

Comment: [1] Is part (b) at least 3 addresses or exactly 3 addresses? [2] See [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).  Recursion may be helpful here.

Comment: If part (b) is exactly 3 addresses, you would have to consider $\binom{8}{3}$ ways of selecting which 3 addresses are correct, the chance of a given address being correct, and then the chance of a derangement among the $5$ remaining addresses.  The chance of address 2 being correct is affected by the assumption that address 1 is correct.

Comment: Part b is exactly 3 addresses

Comment: Sorry, but i don't really understand your method

Comment: a) P(at least one receives)=1-P(nobody receives). To find P(nobody receives) you need derangements.

Comment: Stick with part (a), read the derangements article, and try to apply it to the present problem.  Please edit your question to show what you are trying with the derangements article.  Note that probability can be measured as $$\frac{N\text{(umerator)}}{D\text{(enominator)}}$$ where, in the present problem, there are $D = 8!$ *equiprobable* ways of permuting the addresses.  So, the question resolves to enumerating $N$, as per the cited article.

Comment: The (*natural*) approach of identifying a series of events, and computing the probability of each event, which is the approach that you attempted in your posting, is generally a good method of attack for Probability problems.  However, for Combinatorics-oriented Probability problems, it is often more difficult than the $\displaystyle \frac{N\text{(umerator)}}{D\text{(enominator)}}$ approach that I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: By the way, what is the source of the problem?  If it is from a book or class, then there should have been solved problems, worked examples or theorems that preceded the assignment of this problem.  If that is the case, in addition to studying the derangements article, I suggest that you also study the work that preceded this problem.

Comment: @user2661923 You wrote that "the chance of a given address being correct, and then the chance of a derangement among the 5 remaining addresses", but there is no more addresses. We have only 3 addressees and 5 remaining letters. Am I right?

Comment: What I intended by "the chance of a given address being correct" is that for part (b) you have to first consider the chances of addresses 1,2,and 3 all being correct, and simultaneously, the chances of addresses 4,5,6,7 and 8 being deranged.  Then, you have to consider how many ways there are of selecting $3$ addresses out of $8$ so that those $3$ addresses will be the ones that are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints

- Have a look at [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).
- a) $P(\text{at least one receives})=1-P(\text{nobody receives})$
- b) Find the probability that Albert, Bernard and Cynthia receive and the others do not. Of course there are more possibilities (how many?) and this with equal probability.

Comment: The probability of Albert, Bernard and Cynthis is equal to: $$|A|=\frac {C_{8}^1} {C_{8}^3}$$, $$|B|=\frac {C_{7}^1} {C_{7}^2}$$,$$|C|=\frac {C_{6}^1} {C_{6}^1}$$ and then add all together, am I right?

Comment: No. Have you taken a look at derangements yet? There are $!5$ ways to address the letters in such a way that A,B,C will receive their letter and the others will not. In total there are $8!$ ways to address. So the probability on this event is $\frac{!5}{8!}$. Here notation $!5$ stands for the number of permutations $\sigma$ on $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ that satisfy $\sigma(i)\neq i$ for each $i$.

Comment: Yes I have, but i got wrong answer by using this method

Comment: Have you multiplied the answer concerning A,B,C with factor $\binom83$ afterwards? As I said there are more possiblities for A,B,C.

Comment: Yes I have. Answer by your method is: 0,0029100528. Correct answer is:0.0611111.

Comment: The answer by my method is: $\binom83\times\frac{!5}{8!}=\frac{8!}{3!5!}\frac{!5}{8!}=\frac{!5}{3!5!}=\frac{44}{720}=0.0611111..$

Comment: Yeah, I got it. Thank you!

Comment: If this is enough for you then you can accept the answer.